# Replace deprecated mcrypt_cbc with mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, algorithm, mcrypt

I have an old algorithm to encode passwords which I want to use with PHP 7

```
public function encriptarPass($cadena)
{
     $extra = (strlen($cadena)%8);
     for ($i = $extra; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $cadena .= chr(8-$extra);
     }
     $key = "stack";
     $iv = "stack";                    

     return strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $cadena, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv)));
}
```

I tried to replace mcrypt_cbc with mcrypt_encrypt and I get this error:

> mcrypt_encrypt(): Module initialization failed

I want to update the algorithm to work with old passwords stored in the database. 
I know I should use bcrypt or another algorithm but for the moment I need to update this old algorithm

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003.. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

These two functions will return the same.

```
function encriptarPass($cadena){
    $extra = (strlen($cadena)%8);
    for($i = $extra; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $cadena .= chr(8-$extra);
    }
    $key = "stack";
    $iv = "stack111";
    return strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_3DES, str_pad($key, 24, "\0"), $cadena, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv)));
}

function encriptarPass2($cadena){
    $extra = (strlen($cadena)%8);
    for($i = $extra; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $cadena .= chr(8-$extra);
    }

    $key = "stack";
    $iv = "stack111";
    return strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, str_pad($key, 24, "\0"), $cadena, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)));
}
```

Example:

```
echo encriptarPass('test987x'); // Writes 10C9B50682CC21909AC4346CDFC4586E
echo encriptarPass2('test987x'); // Writes 10C9B50682CC21909AC4346CDFC4586E
```

Comment: It's working, but now I have this problem: `mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 9 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of size 24 supported`
Any way to use it with 9 size key?

Comment: In PHP 5.6 they changed the behaviour such that invalid key sizes are no longer accepted. Before 5.6, the keys were padded with '\0'. I have edited my answer to pad the keys with '\0'.